# How to disable input recommendations?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to prevent recommendations from coming up on an input box I created.

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="message" id="msg" 
        placeholder="Type a message" autocomplete="false">
```

But even with `autocomplete="false"` I still get the following:

[image]

I don't want the recommendations to show up on the input box.

Comment: What happened with _"users posting questions are supposed to make a proper research"_ ?

Comment: The answer to this is very clear in the docs., so need to ask: Why spend all the time to post a question when reading them would solve this in 30 seconds ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you should try using `"off"` instead of `"false"`.

```
autocomplete="off"
```

In context to your given scenario, try the following code snippet

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="message" id="msg" 
   placeholder="Type a message" autocomplete="off">
```

---

If your inputs are wrapped up in a `<form>` you can use this attribute on the form instead of each individual `<input>`.

> It tells the browser not to save data inputted by the user for later autocompletion on similar forms, though heuristics for complying vary by browser.

[Here is the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion).